# Regarding a Nav Bar that keeps going out of control

Tags: html, css

I got this NavBar and no matter what I do to it, it looks really horrible for responsiveness. I can't even get the logo to respond when I shrink my window size down
html

```
 <header>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">

        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a href="index.html">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="app/images/Wildwood_Home_Logo.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="background-color:white !important">
                    <li><a href="WhatWeMake.html" style="">WHAT WE MAKE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="WhoWeAre.html" style="">WHO WE ARE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="WhatTheySaid.html" style="">WHAT THEY SAID</a></li>
                    <li><a href="WhatWeWon.html" style="">WHAT WE WON</a></li>
                    <li><a href="WhatYouSee.html" style="">WHAT YOU'LL SEE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="WhereToBuy.html" style="">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ShopOnline.html" style="">SHOP ONLINE</a></li>
                </ul>

         </div> 
       </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color:#83A4C4;
}
.navbar-brand {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: white; 
}

 .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #83A4C4 !important;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 1310px)
{
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a 
    {
    color:white; 
    }
}
```

the media query I was messing around with, I just had it set to max-width of 767px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the bootstrap online documentation and take the code exactly as it is then modify, this is the code of navbar, delete the parts you don't want in your page

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: That is what I have done, but when i resize the navbar links start to word wrap when i get down to about 1370px or somewhere in there and instead of it wrapping i would rather just have it go into  the navbar collapse

Comment: make sure this happen without any handy style